# Behavior of ratio of statistics

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose we have an n-dimensional vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ with absolutely no assumptions made about it. What can we say about how the ratio

$$
\frac{\bar{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^2}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \theta_i - \bar{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \right)^2}
$$

behaves as $n$ gets large? Even better - can we say anything specifically about how

$$
\frac{n \bar{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^2}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \theta_i - \bar{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \right)^2}
$$

behaves as $n$ gets large?

Comment: Is $\boldsymbol\theta$ supposed to be a vector of random variables?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson no - simply a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: What are $\theta_i$?  *How is this a probability question?*